how override FastApi app.dependency_overrides with a function/ fixture that has an argument?
I have setup tests with a fixture for my deb connection (SQLAlchemy based). The main feature here is that it is rolling back transactions (the tests are not changing the db):
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def connection():
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}".format(
        settings.DB_username, settings.DB_password, settings.DB_hostname, settings.DB_port, settings.DB_name)

    engine = create_engine(
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL,
        connect_args={"options": "-c timezone=utc"}
    )

    return engine.connect()


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def db_session(connection):

    transaction = connection.begin()
    yield scoped_session(
        sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=connection)
    )
    transaction.rollback()

On the other hand i have a fixture that provides a test client. I use this to have integration test that test from api to the DB:
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def client() -> Generator:
    with TestClient(app) as c:
        yield c

Everything is working fine. The problem is that app and all endpoint are injecting the db via not directly but at the end via  db: Session = Depends(get_db). And thus the client is using the "real" connection that does not roll back, and the DB changes are persisted.
Now i tried to override get_db with:
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def client() -> Generator:
    app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = db_session
    with TestClient(app) as c:
        yield c

The problem is: this yields a 422 what is caused by the missing argument db_session needs within my setup. As soon as i remove the line with overrides the test works fine again.
So how to override get_db with my db_session(connection) or in general how to have a TestClient that uses same db_session as other tests that directly rely on.

I wrote an answer, please test it and inform me. If it doesn't work I will try another thing.

get_db will return a database session not a database session fixture. So we need to override the get_db dependency with a function that yields from the db_session fixture.
First, we need to clear any session left after the test using session.remove() like below:
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def db_session(connection):
    transaction = connection.begin()
    session_factory = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=connection)
    session = scoped_session(session_factory)
    yield session
    session.remove()
    transaction.rollback()

After yielding the test client, clear the dependency overrides to avoid any potential issues with subsequent tests.
We override the get_db method to use the db_session fixture also here.
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def client(db_session) -> Generator:
    def override_get_db():
        yield db_session
    app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = override_get_db
    with TestClient(app) as c:
        yield c
    app.dependency_overrides.clear()


thanks for the detailed answer but with this i get: "Failed: Fixture "db_session" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly,"

i fixed it: @pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def client(db_session) -> Generator:
def override_get_db():
        
    yield db_session

app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = override_get_db
with TestClient(app) as c:
    yield c
app.dependency_overrides.clear()  - edit your answer and i will accept. (probably their is even a nicer way)

